# Issue with importing Web3 to Ionic project?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, web3js

I have been trying to import Web3 to Ionic v4 project.

I'm under :

System Version: macOS Mojave 10.14.6

npm: 6.9.0

node : 10.16.1

Steps to reproduce :

1. Start a new Ionic Project :
   `ionic start my-app blank --type=angular`
2. Install Web3 :
   `npm install --save web3`
3. Install @types/web3 :
   `npm install --save @types/web3`
4. Add some code :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Web3 } from 'web3';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  w = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/...apikey...'));

  constructor() {}

  test(){
    console.log(this.w);
  }
}
```

Error here:

```
import { Web3 } from 'web3';
```

Error logs:

Module '"../../../../../../../../../Users/Admin/Desktop/Learn_Ionic/blockchain/my-app/node_modules/@types/web3"' has no exported member 'Web3'

This module can only be referenced with ECMAScript imports/exports by turning on the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag and referencing its default export.

This is my Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.7.1",
    "@types/web3": "^1.0.19",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "web3": "^1.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~2.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^8.9.5",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {}
    },
    "platforms": []
  }
}
```

Comment: try to import like this `import Web3 from 'web3';`

Comment: Got the same error

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/2260#issuecomment-458519127

This might help you solve the issue all you have to do is create a file called patch.js in the root of your application like mentioned in the above issue comment and add a script under scripts section in package.json `postinstall": "node patch.js`

Run `npm install` again and see if it works!